# I am trying to use a do while loop to repeat a certain portion of my program and it refuses to execute properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Okay so as the title said its refusing to execute the stuff right under the "do" function even though as far as i can tell all the parameters for a repeat have been fulfilled.  So far what i get when i run the program is something along the lines of...
"Would you like to search another name?
Please enter Y for yes and n for no:"
looping over and over when i press y

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> vName, vID, vClass;
    string sName, sID, sClass, sSearch, cQuestion;
    int iSize, iStudent;
    // Display initial vector size
    iSize = vName.size();

    cout << "Student list starts with the size:" << iSize << endl;

    // Get size of list from user

    cout << "How many students would you like to add?" << endl;
    cin >> iStudent;
    cin.ignore();
    // Get names, ids, and classes

    for (int i = 0; i < iStudent; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student" << i + 1 << ":\n";
        cout << "Please enter the student name: ";
        getline(cin, sName);
        vName.push_back(sName);

        cout << "Enter ID number ";
        getline(cin, sID);
        vID.push_back(sID);

        cout << "Enter class name ";
        getline(cin, sClass);
        vClass.push_back(sClass);

    }
    // Display header

    cout << "The list of students has the size of: " << iStudent << endl;
    cout << "The Student List" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Name:" << setw(30) << "ID:" << setw(38) << "Enrolled Class : " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n";

    // for loop for displying list
    for (int x = 0; x < vName.size() && vID.size() && vClass.size(); x++)
    {

        cout << vName[x] << "\t \t \t" << vID[x] << "\t \t \t" << vClass[x] << endl;
    }

    // Sorting function
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The Student List after Sorting:" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    sort(vName.begin(), vName.end());

    for (int y = 0; y < vName.size(); y++)
    {
        cout << vName[y] << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n";

    // Search function

    do
    {
        cout << "Please Enter a name to be searched:" << endl;
        getline(cin, sSearch);
        if (binary_search(vName.begin(), vName.end(), sSearch))
        {


            cout << sSearch << " was found." << endl << endl;
        }

        else
        {

            cout << sSearch << " was not found." << endl << endl;


        }

        cout << "Would you like to search another name?" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;
        cin >> cQuestion;

    } while (cQuestion == "Y" || cQuestion == "y");


    cout << "Thank you for using this program!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Posted whole program, please excuse any grammatical mistakes, I'm just trying to get the program down before i go in there and make it pretty.

Comment: You haven't shown your full program, so all I can do is guess, but my guess is that **cQuestion** is a char, and you should write 'Y' and not "Y" in the condition.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, then use the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tail of your loop does this:

```
cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;
cin >> cQuestion;
```

which will consume your string if you entered one, but leave the trailing newline in the input stream. Thus when you return to the top of the loop after entering `Y` or `y`, and do this:

```
cout << "Please Enter a name to be searched:" << endl;
getline(cin, sSearch);
```

the `getline` will extract an empty line.

How to consume the unread newline from the input stream is up to you. You will likely just end up using `.ignore()` as you did prior in your program. Or use `getline` to consume `cQuestion`. You have options. Pick one that works.

And as a side note, I would *strongly* advise you check your stream operations for success before assuming they "just worked". That is a hard, but necessary, habit to break. Something like this:

```
do
{
    cout << "Please Enter a name to be searched:" << endl;
    if (!getline(cin, sSearch))
        break;

    if (binary_search(vName.begin(), vName.end(), sSearch))
    {
        cout << sSearch << " was found." << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << sSearch << " was not found." << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << "Would you like to search another name?" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter Y for Yes and N for No:" << endl << endl;

} while (getline(cin,cQuestion) && (cQuestion == "Y" || cQuestion == "y"));
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe it was a buffer thing.  I'll keep that tip in mind WhozCraig, I'm still new to c++ and i haven't yet figured out how to properly debug programs other than to hit f5.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee you do know how to accept an answer, right?

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee no worries. Just FYI, spend a few minute reading the following:["How to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is *very* helpful for tailoring your questions, ["What kind of questions should I avoid?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) is great to avoiding improper questions for this forum. The general help section under [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is worth the read as well (contains both the prior links). Anyway, glad your problem is solved. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

If cQuestion is a char array then you need to use strcmp or stricmp to compare it with another string i.e. "Y" and "y" in this case. If cQuestion is a single char then you need to compare with 'Y' and 'y' (i.e. with a single quote)

Strings in C++ are not first class types therefore they do not have some of the string operation that exist for other basic types like ints and floats. You do have std::string as part of the standard C++ library which almost fulfills the void.

If you just change the type of cQuestion to std::string your code should work but if you want to stick with chars then you will need to change the quote style.

Comment: Its actually a string.  I've been trying both char data types and strings non seem to be working.  My latest iteration is trying to make it into a string data type... I'll go ahead and post the whole program.