# How do i order vector containing strings in accordance with another pre sorted vector of strings?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

So the program will take in a user's name then ID and store them in vectors vName and vID.  For example i have a code like this that takes a string name

```
cout << "what is your name?";
getline(cin sName)
vName.push_back(sName)

 cout << "what is your name?";
 getline(cin sName)
 vName.push_back(sName)
```

If a user inputs the names Paul and Leto and the IDs 123 and 456 and if i cout the elements inside the vectors i'll get them back exactly as i put them in.  But if i decide to sort vName like this

```
(vName.begin(), vName.end());
```

and i cout the elements Leto will be matched with 123 and Paul will be matched with 456.  How do i prevent that from happening?  How do i make it so that no matter how vName is sorted vID will change so that the IDs will match with the names?

Comment: Store objects that contain both the name and the ID?

Comment: I don't understand are you asking me a question?

Comment: You don't even have to invent a structure. One was provided for you should you choose to take the easy route: `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`. Note however that regardless of how you pursue this, if this is related to [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957725/i-am-trying-to-use-a-do-while-loop-to-repeat-a-certain-portion-of-my-program-and) it poses an interesting challenge concerning things like `binary_search`, namely a custom comparator if all you're searching on is the "name" member. A `std::map` may be more suitable.

Comment: @ZeeZeeZee I am asking if that solution would be suitable.

Comment: @juanchopanza ah okay i understand.  That was my first approach when i was figuring out how to do this, but that is not possible one of the pre-conditions was to store them in different containers.

Comment: @WhozCraig  yes it relates to that question.  The goal at first was just to make that program run which i did thanks to the endl error you pointed me to earlier.  Now (for extra credit) i'm trying to figure out how to keep the IDs and names from getting jumbled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a struct:

```
struct Person {
  string name;
  int id;
};
vector<Person> people;
```

If you don't like that, you could do "proxy sorting" by sorting your ID vector first using the names as the proxy for ordering.  In either of these solutions you will need to implement your own predicate for sorting by the name field.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the requisite predicate for sorting on name-only (or id-only, or name-id, or id-name).

Comment: Okay i think I understand how struct work and that might be a better approach. Thank you

Comment: Just in case, here is a link that explains [proxy sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398819/sort-by-proxy-or-sort-one-container-by-the-contents-of-another-in-c) . You create a third vector of indices, 0 to n-1, sort the vector of indices according to vName, then copy or rerrange vName and vId according to the now sorted vector of indices.